# Hodges-lehmann estimator is ist a U statistic?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, robust

I want to know if the hodges lehmann estimator is U statistic and if yes how to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not, but it is related to the Wilcoxon rank sum test (also called Mann Whitney U test) and the U statistic. See the link below for details.

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_npar1way_details19.htm